# Winston not Logging to console in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, winston

I am confused by winston. I am using the following typescript code to log onto the console in my *.ts file:

```
import { Logger, LoggerInstance } from "winston";

const logger:LoggerInstance = new Logger();
logger.info('Now my debug messages are written to the console!');
```

the console remains empty. There are no compile errors or other issues.

At the same time the following works fine:

```
const wnstn = require("winston");
wnstn.info('Finally my messages are written to the console!');
```

Does anyone have a clue why that is the case? Do I have to configure the Logger differently? How would I use the defaults I get from the second example?

Comment: For other readers: If you're using VSCode's debugger, read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55456463/11041841

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you instantiate a new Logger instance you need to provide it a list of transports so it knows where to send the logs:

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)(),
    new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'somefile.log' })
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 7):

This is the Typescript way to import Winston.

First, be sure you have installed the typing :
`npm i -D @types/winston`

Then, in your script.ts

```
import { Logger, transports } from 'winston';
var logger = new Logger({
  transports: [
    new transports.Console(),
    new transports.File ({ filename: 'somefile.log' })
  ]
});
```

In genral, you can import all constants and types without using `winston.<...>` before.

Answer (score 5):

Well,

thanks to the hint of @idbehold , I found that a plain and easy:

```
import * as winston from "winston";

winston.info('Now my debug messages are written to the console!');
```

works for the default logger..

Comment: I can't write in file

Comment: Because the default is a console output, I think

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am following below file as winston.ts

```
import * as appRoot from 'app-root-path';
import * as winston from 'winston';

// define the custom settings for each transport (file, console)
const options = {
    file: {
        level: 'info',
        filename: `${appRoot}/logs/app.log`,
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: true,
        maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
        maxFiles: 5,
        colorize: false,
    },
    console: {
        level: 'debug',
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: false,
        colorize: true,
    },
};

// instantiate a new Winston Logger with the settings defined above
const logger: winston.Logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File(options.file),
        new winston.transports.Console(options.console)
    ],
    exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
});

// create a stream object with a 'write' function that will be used by `morgan`
const myStream = {
    write: (message: string) => {
        // use the 'info' log level so the output will be picked up by both transports (file and console)
        logger.info(message);
    }
};


export default logger;
```

as using inside app.ts as     `this.app.use(morgan('combined', { stream: winston.stream }));`