# nodeJS Winston module example not logging to console

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

Im trying to test out some winston logging, going by the example [posted Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston#combining-formats) i cannot get this one to work.

I've copy/pasted it onto my js file and pressed F5 in vscode to test the script.

Nothing gets logged.

For a learner its doubly difficult when examples like this dont work as you end up going in circles trying to fix your own environment.

Can someone tell me if this *should* work?

```js
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, label, prettyPrint } = format;
 
const logger = createLogger({
  format: combine(
    label({ label: 'right meow!' }),
    timestamp(),
    prettyPrint()
  ),
  transports: [new transports.Console()]
})
 
logger.log({
  level: 'info',
  message: 'What time is the testing at?'
});
// Outputs:
// { level: 'info',
//   message: 'What time is the testing at?',
//   label: 'right meow!',
//   timestamp: '2017-09-30T03:57:26.875Z' }
```

My nodeJS debug console just quits and displays
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

Comment: This should work. What errors are you getting?

Comment: My nodeJS debug console just quits and displays "Debugger attached. Waiting for the debugger to disconnect..." no errors as such

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The issue is with the debugger configuration. In VSCode you need to add `"outputCapture": "std"` to your launch.json file when configuring the debugger.

This option lets debugger capture the data sent to the std output from your code.

Example configuration:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/winston.js",
      "outputCapture": "std", // <-- ADD THIS LINE
    }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that you can run the code you wrote in node directly and it will log the message correctly.

Comment: brilliant, well spotted.